# Can someone explain immutability/mutability concept in Scala regarding arrays in a little more depth for me?

Tags: arrays, scala, immutability

I am new to Scala and trying to understand the concept of immutability as it relates to Arrays and ArrayBuffers - however, I am getting tripped up with this concept.

I understand `var` to represent a mutable object and `val` to represent an immutable one.

```
var i = 10
i = 12

//OR

val i = 10
i = 12 //error - reassignment to val
```

So I have an example involving arrays and ArrayBuffers and maybe if someone can explain what exactly happens in memory and why these operations are allowed to happen. Like I said, I am still new to Scala and I was just unsure as to why these concepts were:

```
def main(args: Array[String]) :Unit =
  {
    val testArr:Array[Int] = new Array[Int](3)
    testArr(0) = 1
    testArr(1) = 2
    testArr(2) = 3
    val testArr2:Array[Int] = new Array[Int](3)
    //testArr2 = Array(1,2,3) - reassignment to val


    val arrBuffer = new ArrayBuffer[Int]
    arrBuffer += 1
    arrBuffer += 2
    arrBuffer += 3
    //arrBuffer = ArrayBuffer[Int](4,5,6) - reassignment to val
    val addBuffer = ArrayBuffer[Int](4,5,6)
    arrBuffer ++= addBuffer
  }
```

Comment: Think of it this way: a variable is a reference to a patch of memory. If the variable is mutable, `var`, then it can reference (point to) different memory patches at different times. If it is immutable, `val`, then it must always reference (point to) the same memory patch, but that area of memory doesn't have to be immutable. The data structure (memory area) can be mutable/immutable, independent of the variables referencing it.

Comment: What exactly you do not understand? **Arrays** are mutable, you can't do anything about that, if you want an immutable collection, then use one, like a **List**. And **ArrayBuffers** are a mutable collection designed to build arrays of variable size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The memory model differentiates between *pointer-to-data* (memory address) and the *pointed-to-data* (data itself). Consider

```
val x = Array(1,2,3)
```

The key is to understand that `x` does not physically hold the data `1,2,3`, instead it holds just the reference (pointer) to the actual data, that is, it holds the memory location of where the data begins.

Contrast the following situations

```
val xa = List(1,2,3)  // constant pointer to constant data
var xb = List(1,2,3)  // non-constant pointer to constant data
val ya = Array(1,2,3) // constant pointer to non-constant data
var yb = Array(1,2,3) // non-constant pointer to non-constant data
```

For example, `yb` means we can mutate both the address stored in `yb` as well as the data pointed to by `yb`:

```
yb = ya    // mutating the pointer
yb(0) = 42 // mutating the pointed-to-data
```

Ideally, we strive for `xa` usage, that is, for constant pointer to constant data. In functional programming, when we speak of *immutability*, we usually have this `xa` situation in mind.